# Trying to change Informix Database character set

Tags: sql, database, character-encoding, informix

Overview: I am trying to change an Informix database character set from `en_us.819` (`ISO Latin 1` or default character set) to `en_us.57372` (`UTF8` character set).

Details: I have an informix instance lets call it SA that has some database with a character set of `ISO Latin 1` while others are `utf8`. I am currently trying to convert a database lets call it DB1 in SA to `utf8` from `ISO Latin 1`. I have gone through DB1 and ensured that only `ASCII` characters exist in the database. This should mean that no matter if the character encoding is changed the characters will be displayed the same. However I cannot seem to find a way to change the character set of the individual database. I have tried to update the `sysmaster::sysdbslocale` for that database. However that has not worked. Does anyone know of a way to do  this in an Informix database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a supported way to change the code set for an Informix database in situ.

The reliable way to deal with it is to export the data (DB-Export, aka `dbexport`), then import the data specifying the new code set (DB-Import, aka `dbimport`).  Depending on database size and server size, you might need to delete the old database before recreating the new, or you may be able to use RENAME DATABASE to assist you.  In your case, it appears that you won't need to go through a code set conversion process as you have no accented characters to deal with.  If there were any, you'd need to think about using [`iconv`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) or a similar tool to convert the data in the unload data files.

If the existing database is `dbname`, then you might use `rename database dbname to old_dbname` before importing the data as database `dbname`. Or you might import the data as database `new_dbname` and then do two renaming operations (`rename database dbname to old_dbname; rename database new_dbname to dbname;`).  There are many options here.

If that is not acceptable, you may need to contact IBM Informix Tech Support to ask for assistance; they may be able to help you.  But there is more to the change than just changing information in the `sysmaster` database for the given database — it involves writing information in multiple places in the actual database which you want to change, and some of those locations are not accessible via SQL update operations.

Comment: Thank you. This confirmed and clarified what I had been thinking previously.

Answer (score 2):

To add Jonathan's answer, here is a quick example going from 819 to UTF8

Export using the same locales so there is no codeset conversion:

```
informix@irk:/usr3/products/12.10$ dbaccess sysmaster -

Database selected.

> select * from sysdbslocale where dbs_dbsname='stores7';

dbs_dbsname  stores7
dbs_collate  en_US.819

1 row(s) retrieved.

> 
informix@irk:/usr3/products/12.10$ 

informix@irk:/usr3/products/12.10$ export DB_LOCALE=en_US.819
informix@irk:/usr3/products/12.10$ export CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.819
informix@irk:/usr3/products/12.10$ dbexport stores7 -ss
{ DATABASE stores7  delimiter | }

grant dba to "informix";
grant resource to "public";
....
....
update statistics medium for table "informix".sysxtdtypes (
     owner, source)
     resolution   2.00000   0.95000 ;


dbexport completed
informix@irk:/usr3/products/12.10$
```

Rename the database:

```
informix@irk:/usr3/products/12.10$ dbaccess sysmaster -

Database selected.

> rename database stores7 to stores7_819;

Database renamed.

> 
informix@irk:/usr3/products/12.10$
```

Import with the new locale (there will be a conversion from 819 (8859-1) to UTF-8)

```
informix@irk:/usr3/products/12.10$ export DB_LOCALE=en_US.utf8
informix@irk:/usr3/products/12.10$ dbimport stores7
{ DATABASE stores7  delimiter | }

grant dba to "informix";
grant resource to "public";
....
....
dbimport completed

informix@irk:/usr3/products/12.10$ 


informix@irk:/usr3/products/12.10$ dbaccess sysmaster -

Database selected.

> select * from sysdbslocale where dbs_dbsname='stores7';



dbs_dbsname  stores7
dbs_collate  en_US.57372

1 row(s) retrieved.

> 
informix@irk:/usr3/products/12.10$
```

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful and is a great step by step example.